# Docker Gremlin client cannot connect to gremlin server?

Tags: docker, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm running locally a gremlin-client container and a gremlin-server container in 2 separate containers. I'm starting the following like so:

```
docker network create -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true hacker
docker run --network hacker -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4
docker run --network hacker -it tinkerpop/gremlin-console
```

When I try and connect to the remote server from the client like so:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
```

Why is this? I tried to share the network, but still doesn't work. Any ideas? The port is forwarded and matching what is in the remote.yaml file.

## Edit

I got it working by modifying the host in the conf file on the client to read as `host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by modifying the host in the conf file on the client to read as host.docker.internal